# Rails: confirmable in Devise

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, ruby-on-rails-4, devise

I'm using devise with Confirmation but I'm allowing unconfirmed users to  access the website for a period by doing something like that

```
config.allow_unconfirmed_access_for = 15.days
```

Actually I want to display a message for unconfirmed users. How can i do that?

Comment: Is this something you want to show on every page, or just once upon first coming on the site?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

From [devise sources](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/blob/master/lib/devise/models/confirmable.rb#L86):

```
user.confirmed?
```

You can use this condition to display a specific message, flash or anything :)

Comment: That should work, the confirmed_at field is empty if the user has not yet been confirmed and this method works. Maybe you made a mistake in the code that displayed the message ?